# Find all entire functions that satisfy given condition

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Find all the entire function of $f$ such that $f(0)=3$ and $$|f(z)-\cos z|\ge e^{\operatorname{Im} z}$$ 
for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

My approach: 
$$|f(z)|+|\cos z|\ge|f(z)-\cos z|\ge e^{\operatorname{Im}z}=|e^{-iz}|$$ 
Let $h(z) = \frac{e^{-iz}}{f(z)-\cos z}$. Then $h(z)$ is bounded and entire, implies that $h(z)$ = constant $C$. Since $f(0)=3$, we find that $C=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, we construct $$f(z)=2e^{-iz}+\cos z$$
Am I missing out anything?

What I also don't understand is that since we can let $h(z)$ to be anything of our choice, wouldn't there be more than one answer?

Comment: All you need is : "Let $h(z) = \frac{e^{-iz}}{f(z)-\cos z}$. Then $h(z)$ is bounded and entire, implies that $h(z)$ = constant $C$. Since $f(0)=3$, we find that $C=\frac{1}{2}$, therefore $f(z) = 2e^{-iz}+\cos(z)$"

Comment: @user1952009 That's the answer I've given, so you mean my answer is complete? Could you then explain to me why is it that since we can let h(z) to be of our choice, there wouldn't be more than one answer?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "we can let h(z) to be of our choice". And as I wrote, your 1st line with $|f(z)|+|\cos(z)|$ is useless

Comment: @user1952009 Okay, noted on the redundant first line. What I meant was, why is our answer unique? Is h(z) unique?

Comment: It is unique because you proved it is unique. Try replacing $e^{-iz}$ by something else, you'll see what I mean